# Giving each subsequent chat message an alternating class, but all messages get the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, socket.io

I have a simple node JS chat app. I am using express, mongodb, socket.io, and jQuery on the front end.

Everything works, but I want every other message to have a different color and alignment.

These are the CSS classes:

```
  .blueText {
  text-align:left;
  color: #00F;
  }
 .greenText {
  text-align:right;
  color: #0F0;
  }
```

This is the relevant JS function:

```
socket.on('message', addMessages)
  function addMessages(message){

    if ($( "li:odd" )) {
      $("#messages").append(`<li class='blueText'> ${message.name} </li> <p> 
    ${message.message} </p> <span> ${message.id} </span>`)
   }
   else {
    $("#messages").append(`<li class='greenText'> ${message.name} </li> <p> 
   ${message.message} </p> <span> ${message.id} </span>`)
   }}
```

What happens is, all the messages get the blueText class.

Another thing would be, how could I get a unique color for every user.

Comment: Don't you want a user to be able to send multiple messages in a row? In which case, this even/odd method might not be the solution you're looking for

Comment: Kinda thinking your `$( "li:odd" )` selector must not be working the way you intended.

Comment: your conditional is checking if any list elements in a JQuery object are returned that are odd. You want to check if the `length` is even or odd. `($("li").length % 2 === 0)`

Comment: `if ($( "li:odd" )) {` will always be `true` as long as you have at least one `li` because you are not checking any particular `li`, you're just checking to see if there are any odd indexed `li` elements.

Comment: Thank you all, btw how would I check the particular li, just asking. Event.target and "this" do not look like options for that in this case.

Comment: You haven't given us enough context around where the `li` elements are and how you are identifying the one in question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, they are just appended to a container div after every message.

Comment: Then you don't need any JavaScript/JQuery at all. Just change your CSS selectors fo be `li:nth-child(odd)` and `li:nth-child(even)`. That's the real answer here. I'll post with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `if ($( "li:odd" ))` is always true, even if you have no `li` element in your document. `$('yourselector')` always return an object, even if the element you search doesn't exists in your document (just `console.log($('nonexistingelement'))` in your browser console to see the returned object)

Then, if I understand, you want a different color and alignement for all other users than the current one. So the snippet should be this one :

```
socket.on('message', addMessage)

function addMessage(message){
  const messageClass = message.user === currentUser ? 'blueText' : 'greenText' 
  // REPLACE TERNARY STATEMENT WITH YOURS, MATCHING YOUR DATA STRUCTURE
  $("#messages").append(`<li class="${messageClass}"> ${message.name} </li> <p> 
  ${message.message} </p> <span> ${message.id} </span>`)
}
```

Comment: It's possibly a good solution to the use case, but it's not a good Stack Overflow answer because it doesn't address the actual question, nor does it include any explanation for what it does and why.

Comment: I comment if you want but it's pretty obvious

Comment: If it was obvious, then the question wouldn't have been asked. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The Why of my response was obvious, not the question. But you're right, i added the explanation, sorry.

Comment: The response was obvious, but where do I get the current user?

Comment: If you know your user will always have the same name you can use `message.name === currentUser.name` (It's a bad idea, users would want to change their name later). Second option is to give to each user an unique ID, and send the ID in your message, then use `message.userId === currentUser.id `. In all case, you have to store a variable representing your user in the javascript. It's really important to check things like that, display user name, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript or JQuery to get every other element within a group to use a different CSS style. Just use the CSS [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector:

```css
li:nth-child(odd){
 color:red;
}

li:nth-child(even){
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>  
</ul>
```

And, since you may want to toggle not based on odd/even, but based on which user's message are being shown. Just be sure to assign a class to the `li` that designates it as to which user it is and then you just need a little different CSS selector:

```css
li.user1{
 color:red;
}

li.user2{
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="user1">Item</li>
  <li class="user1">Item</li>
  <li class="user2">Item</li>
  <li class="user1">Item</li>
  <li class="user2">Item</li>
  <li class="user2">Item</li>  
</ul>
```